# Vanilla JS equivalent of jQuery's slice method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I implement jQuery's [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method in Vanilla JS? The `slice` method selects a subset of the DOM elements.

Comment: Step by step: use `document.querySelectorAll(...)`, turn the resulting NodeList into an Array, then call `slice` on the Array.

Comment: But then wouldn't you have to turn the array into elements again? Apologies if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: You'd simply iterate over the array. For instance using `forEach()`. jQuery does this implicitly, but with vanilla JS you have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, managed to get my code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll`, then convert it into an array (you can use `slice` or spreading) then call `slice` on the resulting array to select the items you want:

```js
const elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".select"));
console.log(elements.slice(1));
```

```html
<div class="select">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="select">3</div>
<div class="select">4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

You can also use the below equivalents for the first line:

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".select"));
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".select")];
```